# How to call a command (e.g. OPTIMIZE)?

Tags: rest, curl, basex

I am using cURL to interact using the REST interface of BaseX to get resources, delete resources, put new resources, etc. like this: http://docs.basex.org/wiki/REST#Command_Line

Is there any way to call [OPTIMIZE](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands#OPTIMIZE) using that REST interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands like OPTIMIZE can be called like this:

```
curl http://localhost:8984/rest/factbook?command=optimize
```

If the command contains a space, it must be URL escaped to +, e.g. for OPTIMIZE ALL:

```
curl http://localhost:8984/rest/factbook?command=optimize+all
```